# How to delete Label before printing a new one

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

My python code has a ui calendar and button but i don't know how to get the label to print and after destroying the label before it

```
from tkinter import*
from tkcalendar import*

root=Tk()
root.title("Code project")

def selectDate():
    myDate =my_Cal.get_date()
    selectedDate = Label(text=myDate)
    selectedDate.pack()



my_Cal= Calendar(root, setmode = 'day', date_pattern = 'd/m/yy')
my_Cal.pack()

openCal = Button(root, text="Select Date", command=selectDate)
openCal.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

## This keeps reprinting the new selected date once the button is clicked under the old selected date. You can see what it does in the image below.

you may need to zoom in a bit

[image: Tis is what happens after i click the button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define your label just once and update just it's text like this:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkcalendar import*

root=Tk()
root.title("Code project")

selectedDate = Label(root, text="")

def selectDate():
    myDate =my_Cal.get_date()
    selectedDate.config(text=myDate)
    selectedDate.pack()



my_Cal= Calendar(root, setmode = 'day', date_pattern = 'd/m/yy')
my_Cal.pack()

openCal = Button(root, text="Select Date", command=selectDate)
openCal.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you think this is the solution to your question, please mark it as so. If you need any further help, just add a comment to this post.